# Problem with <input name="submit"> if ajax will be fired on a submit event (or function)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The title is a working in progress but here's my problem:

JS:

```
const themeFolder = object_name.templateUrl;
const urlAjax = themeFolder + '/FormHandler.php';
const urlPics = themeFolder + '/pics.php';
const form = $('#contact-form');
form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: urlAjax,
        method: form.attr('method'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            outputmessage.append('<p>A message was sent successfully!</p>');
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$honeypot = $_POST['honeypot'];

if (isset($_POST['submit']) && empty( $honeypot )) {
    var_dump($_POST);
} else {
    echo 'Something went terribly wrong';
}
```

We can ignore the HTML because it is pretty standard, the problem is that, if I will send the email with the only PHP I will be able to retrieve the value from the $_POST['submit'] but if I will try to run the file with ajax (in javascript) for some reason it won't send the $_POST['submit'] value and the script will fail (and it will print something went terribly wrong).

Now, one of the main reasons I'm using the value from the input $_POST['submit'] is that I need to prevent multiple sending of the same email with ajax which of course wouldn't happen in PHP.

On the other hand, I'm not 100% sure why it is failing because of the preventDefault should prevent to run the PHP script from the form which is pretty standard (I'm using TWIG as a template):

```
<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="{{ theme.link }}/FormHandler.php" method="POST" data-parsley-validate="">
    <div class="output-message"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="md-form mb-0">
                <label for="fname">First name *</label>
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" class="form-control" required="">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="md-form mb-0">
                <label for="lname">Last name *</label>
                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" class="form-control" required="">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="md-form mb-0">
                <label for="email">E-mail address *</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="md-form">
                <label for="message">Message *</label>
                <textarea type="text" id="message" name="message" rows="2" class="form-control md-textarea" required=""></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center text-md-left">
        <input name="honeypot" type="text" id="honeypot" value="">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn-primary" name="submit" value="Send message">
    </div>
</form>
```

Any hing?

Comment: Never give an element within a form an `id="submit"`.  It f***s up form submits.  Take that off.

Comment: Is it the problem?

Comment: To follow up on @Taplar comment. Because of legacy API reasons, elements with `id`s create global variables with those `id`s. For that reason, giving things `id`s that match event names or other object names is a problem. Also, don't give buttons a `name` attribute at all as this will cause the `value` of the button to be submitted along with the rest of the form data.

Comment: It's definitely a no-no.  Elements within a form that have ids are made accessable via dot notation.  Such as `document.body.form.fieldId`.  So if you give one an id of submit then `document.body.form.submit` would be the field, but **submit** on a form is already a method.  So by using the id like that, you overlay the method.

Comment: If you have to give it an id, make it `id="submitButton"` to avoid possible function overlays

Comment: The main problem is that `form.serialize()` won't include the values of buttons, since it doesn't know which button was clicked. You need to add that yourself. `form.serialize() + '&submit=true'`

Comment: It works, the problem was the form.serialize() + '&submit=true' for sure.. any idea on how to prevent multiple sending with ajax?

Comment: If you will post the answer I will be glad to mark your solution!

Comment: The line `form.submit(function(e) {`should be `form.submit = function(e) {`, because you are doing a submit not defining it.